# How to fetch JSON from an API and count number of pigeons

Tags: json, go

So I'm trying to get the number of pigeons from a JSON having this format. This JSON contains a lot of bird types and each one is defined by his color and last contact:

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:9001/",
    "pigeons": [
        {
            "color": "white",
            "lastContact": "2020-03-23T14:46:20.806Z"
        },
        {
            "color": "grey",
            "lastContact": "2020-03-23T14:46:20.807Z"
        }
    ],
    "parrots": [
        {
            "color": "green",
            "lastContact": "2020-03-23T14:46:20.806Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Already made this piece of code that gets the JSON from the API, but since I don't have any experience in Go, can you guys help me to count the number of pigeons from here? I don't really care about the number of other bird types.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type pigeons struct {
    Number int `json:"something"`
}

func main() {

    url := "http://localhost:9001"

    birdsClient := http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 2, // Maximum of 2 secs
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    res, getErr := birdsClient.Do(req)
    if getErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(getErr)
    }

    body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if readErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(readErr)
    }

    pigeons1 := pigeons{}
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &pigeons1)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(jsonErr)
    }

    fmt.Println(pigeons1.Number)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the JSON document that comes back, `pigeons` is an array and it looks like the length of that array is the number of pigeons. So if you unmarshal that into a struct that accepts and array for pigeons, you can get the length of it:

```
type pigeons struct {
   Pigeons []interface{} `json:"pigeons"`
}
```

Above, you can unmarshal the `pigeons` field to an interface array because you don't care about the contents of the field. If you need to process contents, you need a separate struct and use the array of that. Then:

```
var p pigeons
json.Unmarshal(body, &p)
fmt.Printf("%d",len(p.Pigeons))
```